# Sql server min and max dates between 2 columns and multiple rows

Tags: datediff, row-number, dateadd, dense-rank, lead

In Sqlserver 2019 script,
I have a table for employee leaves like below format
For example employee has consumed his annual leave days as mentioned below

```
Empcode  LeaveFrom    LeaveTo
A        23/07/2023    01/08/2023
         02/08/2023    03/08/2023
         04/08/2023    04/08/2023



B        10/07/2023    01/08/2023
         02/08/2023    03/08/2023
```

expected Output result
Ecode   **Leave from     Leave to**
A        23/07/2023    04/08/2023
B        10/07/2023    03/08/2023

I have used `lead function`, but still I didn't get what I expected result. looking for suggestions.

I have tried `lead function, row_number(), rank, dense_rank`

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t  got you but you can try this:)

```
SELECT Empcode, MIN(LeaveDate) AS MinLeaveDate, MAX(LeaveDate) AS MaxLeaveDate
FROM (
    SELECT Empcode, LeaveFrom AS LeaveDate FROM Leaves
    UNION
    SELECT Empcode, LeaveTo AS LeaveDate FROM Leaves
) AS CombinedLeaves
GROUP BY Empcode;
```